# Is an event triggered when an HTML link element (<a/>) containing base64 data as href is ready?

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, base64, dom-events

I have created a [webpage](http://barsoap.etrangesmachines.fr/) that basically displays 2 images side by side.

It has a "download" button, which triggers a vanilla Javascript function, which creates a `<canvas>` HTML element and concatenates the two images inside of it. It then creates a link with the base64-encoded result image as `href` and clicks on it:

`<a download="image.png" id="dllink" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABQAAAAMnCAYAAABhnf9DAAAgAElEQVR4nOzdR48kD3rn96j03pfv6qo21dVd3qT3JryP9Jll281..."></a>`

Here is what the function I'm using looks like:

```
/** 
 * Create canvas, draw both images in it, create a link with the result
 * image in base64 in the "href" field, append the link to the document,
 * and click on it
 */
function saveImage() {

    // Get left image
    var imgLeft = new Image();
    imgLeft.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    imgLeft.src = "imgleft/" + idxImageShownLeft + ".jpg";
    imgLeft.onload = function() {

        // Once the left image is ready, get right image
        var imgRight = new Image()
        imgRight.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        imgRight.src = "imgright/" + idxImageShownRight + ".jpg";
        imgRight.onload = function() {

            // Once the right image is ready, create the canvas
            var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
            var widthLeft = parseInt(imgLeft.width);
            var widthRight = parseInt(imgRight.width);
            var width = widthLeft + widthRight;
            var height = imgLeft.height;

            canv.setAttribute("width", width);
            canv.setAttribute("height", height);
            canv.setAttribute("id", "myCanvas");
            canv.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");

            // Draw both images in canvas
            ctx.drawImage(imgLeft, 0, 0);
            ctx.drawImage(imgRight, widthLeft, 0);

            // Create PNG image out of the canvas
            var img = canv.toDataURL("image/png");

            // Create link element
            var aHref = document.createElement('a');
            aHref.href = img;
            aHref.setAttribute("id", "dllink");
            aHref.download = "image.png";

            // Append link to document
            var renderDiv = document.getElementById("render");
            renderDiv.replaceChild(aHref, document.getElementById("dllink"));

            // Click on link
            aHref.click();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that this works fine on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

After a bit of investigating, I realized that by setting a breakpoint before the `aHref.click();` line in Chrome, it worked fine. I *think* that it means that the `aHref.click();` is called **before** the `<a href="data:image/png;base64,...></a>` is ready to be clicked, but I don't know for sure.

- I couldn't find a duplicate of this topic. What keywords should I use just to be 100% sure?
- Am I investigating in the right direction?
- Is there an event I could rely on in order to call `aHref.click();` only when it is ready?

Comment: It works for me, I'm using chrome 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit) on ubuntu.
what is the problem ??

Comment: What is the purpose of `renderDiv.replaceChild(aHref, document.getElementById("dllink"));` ? Is `aHref` , `#dlink` same element ?

Comment: @Alessandro.Vegna: The problem is that when I click the "download" button, sometimes, the result image is opened in my image editor, and sometimes nothing happens.

Comment: @guest271314: What I'm doing is replacing the previous #dllink element with the new one (aHref).

Comment: Not related to your issue, but canvas doesn't have a `crossorigin` attribute.
For your issue, are you sure the images `onload` events are triggered? I personally always prefer setting the src after I declared the onload handlers. Also, I think that on some UAs, the link has to be visible so the `click()` can work.

Comment: @Kaiido: Thanks, I will remove the `crossorigin` attribute for my canvas. I have put trace debugging in my script, and both `onload` events are triggered for my images every time. I will make an attempt setting the `src` after the `onload`. By *visible*, do you mean it has to be appended in the DOM of the page, or that the user must be able to actually **see** it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes by visible I mean the element must not have its CSS `display` property set to `none` neither its `visibility` one to `hidden`. But I think it has changed in most modern browsers since then, and I'm not sure Chrome did ever had this security anyway. But for the appended to document part, I'm sure it is needed, but according to your given code, it should not be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in an init function that gets called when the window completes loading.

```
function init() {
  aHref.click();
}
window.onload = init;
```

Its similar to the vanilla equivalent of jQuery's .ready() method.

Comment: I already have a `window.onload` function in [my code](https://github.com/Alfred456654/amegalWebsite/blob/master/js/doubleScroll.js) unfortunately... Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: You could always put it in a timeout function to give the SVG a chance to load before calling click on it. Set it to like 1 second. Not ideal, but it is a work around.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it helped me shed some light on the problem. Apparently, using something like this didn't help: `setTimeout(function() { aHref.click(); }, 3000);`. However, this worked better, for some reason: `setTimeout(function() { alert("About to click..."); aHref.click(); }, 3);`. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

`aHref` , `document.getElementById("dllink")` appear to be same element ? Though `"dllink"` has not yet been appended to `document` when `.replaceChild` called ?

Try substituting

```
renderDiv.appendChild(aHref);
```

for

```
renderDiv.replaceChild(aHref, document.getElementById("dllink"));
```

Comment: Yes, `document.getElementById("dllink")` is the previously used element, and `aHref` is the newly created one. I use `.replaceChild` to substitute the old one for the new one. Before doing this, I used to append all the time, thus creating a new element in my document at each click. Unfortunately, the aforementioned problem existed also back then.

Comment: @AlfredDupont To avoid possible duplicate `id`s in document, could remove existing `#dllink` before appending new `#dllink` ? Can create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate issue ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am already using `repaceChild` instead of `appendChild` so that at any given time, there is only one element whose id is `dllink`.

I have tried making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saejcv6j/1/) but for some reason I didn't succeed... Sorry.

Tomorrow I will read how to make a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and try again.